# passing collection as ajax parameter backbone

Tags: jquery, backbone.js-collections

I would like to pass this collection as a parameter to an ajax call as follows

```
$.ajax({
   url:"FlightDetails",
   dataType:"JSON",
   data: { flights : flightsCollection"},
   success: function() {},
   error: function() {}
});
```

But my code is breaking for some odd reason. My page freezes out of nowhere. What is the mistake I am making? Is there another alternative I can do the same?

Answer (score 0):

To answer my question, all thats needed to be done is using toJSON() function
Which means the code becomes

```
$.ajax({
 url:"FlightDetails",
 dataType:"JSON",
 data: { flights : flightsCollection.toJSON()},
 success: function() {},
 error: function() {}
 });
```

That will change the collection to a JSON object and can be used the same way as any other json object.